# Start Multiple Thread Simultaneous

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> ncmFile=new List<string>();
            ncmFile.Add("NCM1");
            ncmFile.Add("NCM2");

            List<string> naeFile = new List<string>();
            naeFile.Add("NAE1");
            naeFile.Add("NAE2");


            for (int i = 0; i < ncmFile.Count; i++)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart( ()=>NCMNAEConversion(ncmFile[i], naeFile[i])) );
                t.Start();
            }
        }

        public void NCMNAEConversion(string ncmFileName, string naeFile)
        {

            //conversion process
        }
```

Note : the sample code is above, i want to run NCMNAEConversion method simulteneously  based no ncmList. wether this threads run simultaneous?

Comment: Yes, though there is no pure simultaneous in computers. By the way, you can easily test in with `Console.WriteLine` from within the `NCMNAEConversion` method

Comment: Warning - you're capturing the `i` variable in your lambdas - it's likely that multiple threads will in fact use the same `i` value (and some may use a value that's outside the bounds of the arrays)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `Parallel` class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

As Gdoron says there is no real parallel processing, but with this class CPU will assign every thread some time and then step to the next one and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the TPL instead of starting threads by yourself:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

List<string> ncmFile = new List<string>();
ncmFile.Add("NCM1");
ncmFile.Add("NCM2");

List<string> naeFile = new List<string>();
naeFile.Add("NAE1");
naeFile.Add("NAE2");

Parallel.For(0, ncmFile.Count, (i) =>
{
    string ncm = ncmFile[i];
    string nae = naeFile[i];
    NCMNAEConversion(ncm, nae);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ThreadPool to create several threads.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(NCMNAEConversion), new string[]{ ncmFile[i], naeFile[i]});

public void NCMNAEConversion(object state) 
{ 
    //conversion process
    string[] values = (string[])state;
}
```